# PhpStorm with Xdebug can not STEP debug

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

```
PHP VERSION :7.3.6
XDEBUG VERSION: 2.7.2
```

I can not step debug but the `xdebug` remote port is listening, why ?

Also, `xdebug` had hit the target point. It just can not step work.

Comment: This is my php.ini's xdebug conf:
[xdebug]
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host="127.0.0.1"
xdebug.remote_port="9666"
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"

xdebug.default_enable = On
xdebug.auto_trace=Off
xdebug.collect_params=Off
xdebug.collect_return=Off

Comment: What is you PhpStorm version?

Comment: Please also check this troubleshooting guide: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#Troubleshooting_PHP_debugging.xml

Comment: There is also very clever rule which can be set in the php.ini => https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log